# SIP Demo without Registration

Tags: android, sip

Im using the SIPDemo and it doesnt register with a Server. I can make calls but cant receive calls. I think the Problem is the registration.
My Question: Is it possible to make a peer-to-peer call without a registration using the android API?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Tell us, [what have you tried](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/) so far?

Answer (score 0):

yes you can make peer-to-peer call without a registration.

but you must register users to server manually.

Comment: I want to make calls with static IPs, because I know the Ip of all SIP-Clients and make the call with the IP. My Question is how could I receive Calls if the function register() from SipManager isnt called. Because in the function description of register() it says something like: register() is still needed to be called at least once in order for the SIP service to notify the caller with the PendingIntent when an incoming call is received. Is it possible?

Comment: Can someone please reply to Johan's query. Which turns out to be same as mine. SOME1...